# Under what cirumstances does ConcurrentDictionary.TryRemove() return false?

Tags: c#, collections, concurrency

I've been searching for a way to remove an item from a concurrent dictionary. For some reason there's no `Remove` method, but there's a `TryRemove` method, that returns a `bool`. In MSDN [it's said](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287129(v=vs.110).aspx) that `false` is returned in case the process "failed", but doesn't say in what way.

1. Is it false when the element is absent only?
2. Is it false when the element couldn't be removed due to a lock?

Comment: `Try do something` is a pattern, it does exist for `Dictionary` as well and some other data structures. it has nothing to do with concurrency.

Comment: Every `Try...` method returns a `bool` if the conversion (or whatever) was successful. The `ConcurrentDictionary` allows multiple threads to access a Dictionary instance. So it's possible that the key was already removed. Similar to the `TryAdd`-method which returns false if the key was already there. You may find this helpful: http://www.dotnetperls.com/concurrentdictionary (_"The reason they cannot do something is usually because the given key is invalid. It may have been changed on another thread"_)

Comment: 1st option only: when there's no key to remove; locking is ConcurrentDictionary internal implementation and it should not be visible from outside.

Comment: That's the answer. Could someone post it?

Comment: (I've edited the title to better reflect the question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1st option only: when there's no key to remove; locking is
>   ConcurrentDictionary internal implementation and it should not be
>   visible from outside.

According to comment by Dmitry Bychenko.